# Use Lambda expressions to perform filter

Tags: c#, android, filter, lambda

I have a class of items and I want it so when a user types in a text box it performs the search and updates the adapter. So far the filtering works however it does not return a result which I believe is because my lambda expression is incorrect.

```
// Add Filter
        _inputSearch.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var filter = ItemList.Where(d => d.ItemID.Contains(_inputSearch.Text)).ToList();
            // create our adapter
            itemList = new Adapters.TaskListAdapter(this, filter);

            //Hook up our adapter to our ListView
            _listView.Adapter = itemList;
        };
```

Comment: So what results does it give and what results do you expect? It's not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var filter = ItemList.Where(d => d.ItemID.ToLower().Contains(_inputSearch.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
```